# UISwitch in UITableViewCell freezes app when cell is selected, doesn't freeze on UISwitch toggle

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

I have a UITableView in which for some of the cells I programatically add a UISwitch as an accessoryView. For delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I use the following: `tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)`immediately, if the cell is of a custom class I do some additional actions (expanding/collapsing) - the UISwitch is not of a custom class, it is an accessoryView of a regular cell so `tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)`is executed when the cell is clicked, and that is all. The problem is that with the cells that have a UISwitch as an accessoryView, if you toggle the switch on/off it works fine - but the second you press anywhere else on the same cell, it stays highlighted and the app freezes. Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

didSelectRowAtIndexPath Function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        // Deselect automatically if the cell is a DatePickerCell/PickerCell.
        let cell = self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)

        if (cell.isKindOfClass(DatePickerCell)) {

            let datePickerTableViewCell = cell as! DatePickerCell
            datePickerTableViewCell.selectedInTableView(tableView)
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        } else if(cell.isKindOfClass(PickerCell)) {

            let pickerTableViewCell = cell as! PickerCell
            pickerTableViewCell.selectedInTableView(tableView)
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        }
}
```

And I set the switches as follows:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            let row = indexPath.row

            allDaySwitch.on = false
            gstSwitch.on = false

            //Assigns UISwitch cells and UITextField cells
            if(indexPath.section == 0) {

                let rowTitle = mainOptions[row]
                cell.textLabel?.text = rowTitle
                cell.accessoryView = nil

            } else if(indexPath.section == 1) {

                let rowTitle = dateOptions[row]

                if(rowTitle == "All Day") {
                    cell.accessoryView = allDaySwitch
                } else {
                    cell.accessoryView = nil
                }

                cell.textLabel?.text = rowTitle

            } else if(indexPath.section == 2) {

                let rowTitle = alertOptions[row]
                cell.accessoryView = nil
                cell.textLabel?.text = rowTitle

            } else {

                let rowTitle = billingOptions[row]

                if(rowTitle == "Tax Included") {
                    cell.accessoryView = gstSwitch
                } else {
                    cell.accessoryView = nil
                }

                cell.textLabel?.text = rowTitle
            }

            return cell
    }
```

selectedInTableView function:

```
public func selectedInTableView(tableView: UITableView) {
        expanded = !expanded

        UIView.transitionWithView(rightLabel, duration: 0.25, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.rightLabel.textColor = self.expanded ? self.tintColor : self.rightLabelTextColor
            }, completion: nil)

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, it's already set up in your `dataSource` method. It looks like you're using static cells in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you can easily do the same for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

```
switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
       // do Something
    case 1:
       // do Something
    default: break
}
```

Additionally, the issue is that you are passing in the `tableView` which isn't actually be accessed correctly by the `UITableViewCell`. `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` should be called on your view controller as your UITableViewCell has no idea (nor cares) what's going on in your tableView itself.

Comment: But I need it to take specific action depending on what type of cell it is, as I have customer classes for certain cells. So that's how I am able to compare @jasonnoahchoi

Comment: what does your `selectedInTableView` in datePickerCell look like?

Comment: You should get rid of the tableView parameter and the beginUpdates() and endUpdates() in the cell and call that in your view controller instead because your cell doesn't have proper access to the tableView

Comment: Nice work, thank you! - Can you update your answer? Cheers

Comment: nice! i'm glad it was helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101736/discussion-between-cwattsdis-and-jasonnoahchoi).